# Crosswalk: XWalkUIClient.onCreateWindowRequested() : How to get a hold of the requested url?

Tags: android, crosswalk

I want to open the default browser in Android whenever some javascript code executes 'window.open()' in a crosswalk webview.

I have created a class that extends `XWalkUIClient` and overrides [onCreateWindowRequested()](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs_v5/org/xwalk/core/XWalkUIClient.html#onCreateWindowRequested(org.xwalk.core.XWalkView,%20org.xwalk.core.XWalkUIClient.InitiateBy,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback)). This method gets called when `window.open()` is called which is the desired behaviour. However, I don't know how to get the url parameter that `window.open()` is called with. Does anyone know how I can get retrieve the url?

Once I get the url, I want to open this url with the following code:

`Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the url directly, but with a temporary `XWalkView` and a custom `XWalkUIClient` in `onCreateWindowRequested`, you can achieve what you're after.

The following code example shows how to access the url in `onCreateWindowRequested`:

```
xWalkView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(xWalkView) {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindowRequested(XWalkView view, InitiateBy initiator, final ValueCallback<XWalkView> callback) {
        // Create a temporary XWalkView instance and set a custom XWalkUIClient
        // to it with the setUIClient method. The url is passed as a parameter to the
        // XWalkUIClient.onPageLoadStarted method.
        XWalkView tempView = new XWalkView(getActivity());
        tempView.setUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(tempView) {
            @Override
            public void onPageLoadStarted(XWalkView view, String url) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Return the temporary XWalkView instance with the callback to start the page
        // load process in tempView.
        callback.onReceiveValue(tempView);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, which version of crosswalk did you use in your example?